# sed wildcard search replace

Tags: bash, search, replace, sed, wildcard

I'm using sed on Centos, bash.

I want to replace everything between \plain and }} with a space in the below line of text:

```
stuff here \plain \f2\fs20\cf2 4:21-23}} more stuff over here, could be anything.
```

The text between \plain and }} will vary (different numbers/numbers). How can I do a wildcard to include everything between \plain and }}.

I was hoping a simple * would grab everything between the two but the wildcard in shell doesn't seem to work like this:

```
s/\\plain *}}/ /g;
```

The answer may be something incorporating this? [a-zA-Z0-9.] but that doesn't account for the backslashes, colons, and dashes in the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add dot before * to match everything.

i.e. `s/\\plain .*}}/ /g` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex ...

```
^\\plain .*}}$
```

... will match lines beginning with `\plain`, having anything in the middle, and ending with `}}`.

If that's no use, instead of `.*` to match everything, use `^` (negation) to match everything that's not `}}`.

Comment: I clarified my question. The above does work if that's the only thing on the line. There's text before the \plain and after the }}.

Comment: Remove the `^` and `$` that signal beginning and end of line, and use lazy matching