# Updating IP values after a specific string in a configuration file using SED

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I'm trying to figure out how to replace some text in a config file even though I don't always know the full content.

For example:

```
[IP] 192.168.1.0
```

I want to change the IP value even though I may not know what it might be at the time.

I think SED is the way to do, but that only seems to deal with replacements where you know exactly what you are replacing:

```
 sed -i -e 's/few/asd/g' hello.txt
```

Is there a way I can match on the `[IP]` and switch out the line for a new one, even if I dont know what the value of the IP is?

Comment: In `s/pattern/replacement/`, pattern can match arbitrary regular expressions rather than fixed strings.

Comment: Just use: `sed 's/\[IP\] .*/replacement/' file`

Comment: Easier with awk without regex: `awk -v repl="$newip" '$1=="[IP]"{$2 = repl} 1' file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed wildcard substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6258643/608639), [Using SED with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9189120/608639), [sed wildcard search replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5843870/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
s="[IP] 192.168.1.0"
ip="192.168.15.24"
sed -i "s/^\[IP] .*/[IP] $ip/" hello.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/jqbivS).

Here, `^\[IP] .*` matches

- `^` - start of a line
- `\[IP]` - an `[IP]` substring
- - a space
- `.*` - any 0 or more characters.

If you want to use more specific matching pattern, consider chaning `^\[IP] .*` to

```
^\[IP] [0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}$
```

Or

```
^\[IP] [0-9]\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}$
```

Here, `[0-9]\{1,3\}` matches 1, 2 or 3 digits, and `\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}` matches 3 repetitions of `.` and 1, 2 or 3 digits up to the end of a line (`$`).

Note that this "backslash hell" is due to the fact this regex is POSIX BRE compliant. To get rid of them, use a POSIX ERE regex by passing `-E` option:

```
sed -i -E "s/^\[IP] [0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$/[IP] $ip/" hello.txt
```

Comment: Just FYI, a [regex for IP matching in `grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482951/extracting-ip-address-from-a-line-from-ifconfig-output-with-grep).